# SQL subquery and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want a few columns and only if there are multiple appointment dates on the same day for an employee.

`Appointment` table

Initial

| employeeID | employeename | appointment_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | James | 1/1/2020 | office |
| 11 | James | 1/1/2020 | meeting |
| 11 | James | 1//2020 | school |
| 12 | Marsha | 2/1/2020 | office |
| 13 | Shane | 3/1/2020 | school |
| 13 | Shane | 3/1/2020 | office |

Expected

| employeeID | employeename | appointment_date | type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | James | 1/1/2020 | office | 3 |
| 11 | James | 1/1/2020 | meeting | 3 |
| 11 | James | 1//2020 | school | 3 |
| 13 | Shane | 3/1/2020 | school | 2 |
| 13 | Shane | 3/1/2020 | office | 2 |

Marsha is excluded because there is only 1 appointment for that date

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    a.employeeID,
    a.appointment_date,
    a.type,
    (SELECT COUNT(a.employeeID) 
     FROM a.employeeID 
     GROUP BY a.employeeID 
     HAVING COUNT(a.employeeID) > 1)
FROM 
    appointment a
WHERE 
    a.date BETWEEN '1/1/2020' AND '12/31/2020'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server management studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the windowed version of `count()`.

```
SELECT x.employeeid,
       x.employeename,
       x.appointment_date,
       x.type,
       x.count
       FROM (SELECT a.employeeid,
                    a.employeename,
                    a.appointment_date,
                    a.type,
                    count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.employeeid,
                                                a.appointment_date) count
                    FROM appointment a
                    WHERE a.date >= '2020-01-01'
                          AND a.date < '2021-01-01') x
       WHERE x.count > 1;
```

Notes:

- `employeename` shouldn't be in the table `appointment`, it's redundant. There should be a table for the employees in which the name (and other details) can be looked up by the ID.
- Avoid using `BETWEEN` for date/times. Use a range that compares the end excluding it. That way you don't have to worry about the query no longer fetching all the right records when the precision is increased.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
   SELECT 
        a.employeeID,
        a.employeeName,
        a.appointment_date,
        a.type,
        T.count
    FROM 
       appointment a
    Left Join (SELECT b.EmployeeID, COUNT(b.employeeID) count 
              FROM appointment b
                 WHERE a.appointment_date >= '2020-01-01'
                 AND b.appointment_date < '2021-01-03'
                 GROUP BY b.employeeID )T on T.EmployeeID=a.EmployeeID
           WHERE 
            T.count>1
```